# UIWebView scrolling horizontally in iOS app but not in Chrome

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a website that when I load in Chrome on iPhone, the width loads perfectly however when I add that url to a webview in my iOS app the web page seems to scroll slightly horizontally, its not quite an exact fit

Any idea why this could be?

Comment: "A webview in Xcode"? Surely you meant "a webview in my iOS application"...!?

Comment: It would definitely be helpful if you posted the web site URL.

Comment: Perhaps the WebView in your app has different dimensions, and that's causing something in your page's CSS to be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is easy fix.

Go to interface builder and make option **Scales Page To Fit** checked
[image: IB - WebView]